# PHP preg_grep Variable

Tags: php, html

Using preg_grep, how would you search for an exact match of a variable? I was able to get the following code to return anything containing those letters, but can't seem to get only exact match.

$o is an array
$a for example would be "at"

```
$c=preg_grep("/$a/",$o);
echo implode($c, ' ');
```

And the output would be something like: at cat hat mat

Using logic from bash grep I thought I could use ^\$a$ but apparently isn't correct. Any ideas?

Comment: You're not anchoring `^$` the regex. And if you're just after exact matches, why not just use `in_array()` or something. But what's the purpose anyway? You expect just one exact result, being $a ?

Comment: *EDIT: Sorry, typo:Yes it is expected that there is on one exact match on a line. For example a line might have " 1 4 at", if $a is at, I want to print that whole line that has the 3rd column has "at" and not "cat". @mario

Comment: So you just want to anchor words then? Use `\b`, see [regexp.info](http://regexp.info/); don't forget the `preg_quote` as sectus suggested.

Comment: \b works, Thanks. I'll have to read up more on regex, still learning! @mario

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla PHP:

```
preg_grep('/\b' . preg_quote($a, '/') . '\b/', $o);
```

You can also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com)

```
Pattern::inject('\b@\b', [$a])->forArray($o)->filter();
```